# Flutter: getting the method '[]' was called on null even I'm getting data from the api

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using chopper for calling the api which works fine but when try to show it in ui it shows error.
I'm using  `newsapi.org`

my chopper service file and I have generated the `*.chopper.dart` file

```
import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';

part 'chopper_api_service.chopper.dart';

@ChopperApi(baseUrl: 'https://newsapi.org/v2')
abstract class ChopperApiService extends ChopperService {
  
  @Get(path: '/top-headlines' )
  Future<Response> getNews(
      {@Query('apiKey') String apiKey = 'Secret',
        @Query("q") String q = "health",
        @Query("sortBy") String sort = "publishedAt",
        

      });

  static ChopperApiService create() {
    final client = ChopperClient(
      baseUrl: 'https://newsapi.org/v2',
      services: [
        _$ChopperApiService(),
      ],
      converter: JsonConverter(),
    );
    return _$ChopperApiService(client);
  }
}
```

where I'm trying to show it

```
import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fruitley/week-5/bonus/chopper/models/chopper_api_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ChopperNewsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChopperNewsCardState createState() => _ChopperNewsCardState();
}

class _ChopperNewsCardState extends State<ChopperNewsCard> {
  ChopperApiService chopperApiService;
  Future<Response> apiResponse;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chopperApiService = ChopperApiService.create();
    apiResponse = chopperApiService.getNews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Response>(
        future: apiResponse,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            final  news = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.bodyString);
            print(news);//<---- response does get printed
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: news.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Text(news[index]['title']),//<----here I'm getting null
              );
            });
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```

the response I'm getting while printing

```
{status: ok, totalResults: 22, articles: [{source: {id: news24, name: News24}, author: null, title: JUST IN | Eastern Cape health MEC Sindiswa Gomba fired, description: Eastern Cape health MEC Sindiswa Gomba has been fired to allow her time to focus on her Nelson Mandela funeral fraud case., url: https://www.news24.com/news24/SouthAfrica/News/just-in-eastern-cape-health-mec-sindiswa-gomba-fired-20210218, urlToImage: https://cdn.24.co.za/files/Cms/General/d/10923/2e695d030e754090a3cdf951562b2987.jpg, publishedAt: 2021-02-18T12:11:07+00:00, content: Eastern Cape health MEC Sindiswa Gomba has been fired from her position to allow her time to focus on her Nelson Mandela funeral fraud case.
The announcement was made by Premier Oscar Mabuyane durin… [+232 chars]}, {source: {id: rte, name: RTE}, author: RTÉ News, title: No jab, no job - Vatican issues decree over vaccine, description: The Vatican has told employees that they may risk losing their jobs if they refuse to get a Covid-19 vacc<…>
```

I think I'm doing something wrong in api call also.

Can anyone help me solving this?

Comment: how does `Response` class look?

Comment: @TirthPatel hello I have updated the question with the response, I don't l know how to format it so I have just pasted there

Comment: I meant Response class file but it seems it comes from a package. Can you post output of `jsonDecode`?

Comment: @TirthPatel that is what I'm getting in the jsonDecode while doing `print(news)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to access `articles` key first because that contains the list of news. Each individual item of `articles` key holds `title`, `description`, `url`, etc.

```
Text(news['articles'][index]['title']),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Replace your code with this

    import 'dart:convert';

import 'package:chopper/chopper.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:fruitley/week-5/bonus/chopper/models/chopper_api_service.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';

class ChopperNewsCard extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _ChopperNewsCardState createState() => _ChopperNewsCardState();
}

class _ChopperNewsCardState extends State<ChopperNewsCard> {
  ChopperApiService chopperApiService;
  Future<Response> apiResponse;
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    chopperApiService = ChopperApiService.create();
    apiResponse = chopperApiService.getNews();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return FutureBuilder<Response>(
        future: apiResponse,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            final  news = jsonDecode(snapshot.data.bodyString);
            print(news);//<---- response does get printed
            return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: news.length,
                shrinkWrap: true,
                itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Card(
                child: Text(news['articles'][index]['title']),,//<----here I'm getting null
              );
            });
          } else {
            return CircularProgressIndicator();
          }
        });
  }
}
```